# How to know who is running a DELETE via trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a trigger on my table,

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_MyTable_Delete ON MyTable
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    -- INSERT INTO TABLE the Id, 
END;
```

So that I want to know who is running. So, I want to know Login, ProgramName, HostName and any information that can inform me who is running the script.

Comment: Start with `@@spid` variable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/spid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: There are built in functions returning all three of the things you state

Comment: @MartinSmith can u please tell me?

Comment: @MartinSmith got it thanks `SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName, SUSER_NAME() LoggedInUser, CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') as VARCHAR(256)), APP_NAME()`

Answer (score 1):

first of all

```
CREATE TABLE temp_sp_who2
(
  SPID INT,
  Status VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  Login SYSNAME NULL,
  HostName SYSNAME NULL,
  BlkBy SYSNAME NULL,
  DBName SYSNAME NULL,
  Command VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  CPUTime INT NULL,
  DiskIO BIGINT NULL, -- int
  LastBatch VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  ProgramName VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  SPID2 INT
  , RequestId INT NULL --comment out for SQL 2000 databases

)
```

after that write this in trigerr

```
INSERT  INTO temp_sp_who2
EXEC sp_who2 @@spid
```